# IBM API Connect developer portal admin link missing

Tags: ibm-cloud, apiconnect

I have setup an API Connect developer portal in the sandbox catalog (I've been following the basic tutorials about configuring an API developer portal found [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMNED_2018/com.ibm.apic.devportal.doc/tapim_tutorial_creating_portal.html)).

I receive a message saying that i'll get a one time login link so that i can login to the portal as admin and reset my password. However, this never arrives. I have tried configuring the portal a number of times now and this link never comes. Therefore i'm unable to login as admin.

I've also tried using the 'request new password' option on the developer portal itself and entering my email but this also does not work

Is there a way I can retrieve the login link?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a number of things:

1) the IBM emails often get flagged as spam
2) the IBM email server, or rather the people they've contracted this out to, doesn't fully comply with DKIM/SPF security, so if you are on a corporate server that requires this then you won't get your emails.

The workaround I've done in the past is spin up a gmail account and be sure to check my spam folder.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question. But anyone looking to obtain the admin password in such cases, viz. Mail getting flagged as spam, or if you don't have a functional mail server.

You have to log in to the portal server/pod via ssh.
Run the command `list_sites` to list available sites
then you can run the command `site_login_link <site_url OR site_uuid>` and it will generate a one-time login link for you on the CLI.

Especially useful on test/POC systems where you don't have SMTP setup but want to try out something.